# Decrypt "Saved Password" from Chrome in C

Tags: python, c, windows, winapi, encryption

As a part of a project, we are trying to decrypt saved password in Google Chrome. After little digging we understand that Chrome encrypt the password using CryptProtectData function which let you encrypt the data using login user credential i.e. the encrypted data can only be decrypted on same machine by same user (other users also if appropiate parameters are provided).

Anyhow, I have previously wrote a Python script to do exactly that and it works perfectly fine.

```
from os import getenv, unlink
from shutil import copy
import sqlite3
import win32crypt

dbpath = "C:\Users\\"+ getenv('username') +"\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\\"
copy(dbpath + "Login Data", dbpath + "Login Data.db")
conn = sqlite3.connect(dbpath + "Login Data.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT action_url, username_value, password_value FROM logins')
for result in cursor.fetchall():
    password = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(result[2], None, None, None, 0)[1]
    print result[0] + " - " + result[1] + ":" + password
conn.close()
unlink(dbpath + "Login Data.db")
```

But due to project requirement, i have to code it in C language.
So i wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Wincrypt.h>
#include "sqlite3.h"

static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
   int i;
   fprintf(stderr, "%s: \n", (const char*)data);
   for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
      if (i == 2 ){
        DATA_BLOB DataIn;
        DATA_BLOB DataOut;
        BYTE *pbDataInput = (BYTE *) argv[i];
        DWORD cbDataInput = strlen((char *) pbDataInput) + 1;
        DataIn.pbData = pbDataInput;
        DataIn.cbData = cbDataInput;
        if (CryptUnprotectData (&DataIn, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, &DataOut))
          printf("%s\n", DataOut.pbData);
        else
          printf("Error number %x.\n", GetLastError());
      }
      // printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
   }
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   sqlite3 *db;
   char *zErrMsg = 0;
   int rc;
   char *sql;
   const char* data = "Callback function called";

   /* Open database */
   rc = sqlite3_open("Login Data.db", &db);
   if( rc ){
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      return(0);
   }else{
      fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
   }

   /* Create SQL statement */
   sql = "SELECT action_url, username_value, password_value from logins";

   /* Execute SQL statement, */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   }else{
      fprintf(stdout, "Operation done successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);
   return 0;
}
```

It compiled correctly without any error, but the decrypted data was not correct.

```
C:\>gcc -o decryptor decryptor.c sqlite3.o -lcrypt32

C:\>decryptor.exe
Opened database successfully
Callback function called: Important Data
Error Number 57.

Operation done successfully

C:\>
```

According to [System Error Codes (0-499)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx),
0x57 is for ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (The parameter is incorrect)

What am I missing?

Comment: What are the values of `argv[i]` (or since it will just be encrypted text: does it look right? Compare to what you get in python byte-by-byte) and what is the value of `cbDataInput`? My first guess is that `strlen` isn't working right (e.g. perhaps `argv[i]` isn't null-terminated?)

Comment: @TimSweet how to suggest on doing that? Like using debugger (IDA Pro or gdb).

Comment: Personally I would use a debugger (since you're using Windows: Visual Studio Community is free and very popular, otherwise gdb works). Or just use printf to print the bytes out similar to your commented out line in `callback()`.

Comment: @TimSweet I will try to print the parameters in hex in code itself and will update you in few hours. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TimSweet i wrote a simple program which will encrypt and decrypt a string and i tried to print the hex value. i am able to print the hex for plain text but not encrypted text.

Comment: @TimSweet can you please try in on your machine?

Comment: I don't have sqlite3 on my computer, and trying to build it per the instructions on the website isn't working for me (I'm using Visual Studio, not gcc). So no I can't test it on my computer. Why can't you print the encrypted text? I can probably help if you share more details.

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine for me as you have your crypted data in 2hex.txt (just saved it from DB Browser). Your problem was really in strlen() function, because it meets first "0" in byte sequence and stops. Just avoid it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Wincrypt.h>


int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    DATA_BLOB DataIn;
    DATA_BLOB DataOut;
    char result[1000]="";
    unsigned char buf[1000]="";
    int tmpbuf;
    int i=0;
    fp=fopen("3hex.txt","rb");
    printf ("Crypted data:\n");
    for(i=0;(tmpbuf=getc(fp))!=EOF;i++)
    {
        buf[i]=tmpbuf;
        if (i%16==0) printf("\n");
        printf("%02X ",buf[i]);
    }
    DataIn.pbData=buf;
    DataIn.cbData=i+1;
    if (CryptUnprotectData (&DataIn, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, &DataOut)) 
    {
        for (i=0;i<DataOut.cbData;i++)
        {
            result[i]=DataOut.pbData[i];
        }
        result[i+1]='\0';
        printf("\nResult as string: %s\n", result);

    }

    else printf("Error number %x.\n", GetLastError());
}
```